# ICU is required for WebKit issue

Tags: windows, qt, webkit

I want to build `WebKit` module for `Qt 5.7.1` and for `Windows`.

[image]

The problem is `ICU is required`. I have downloaded `ICU` (http://download.qt.io/development_releases/prebuilt/icu/prebuilt/) compiled libs for `VS 2013` and added the directory to the `PATH` but the error is still exists. Thanks.